# How to generate UI tests from a dsl ?

Tags: java, android, groovy, android-uiautomator

I'm not sure this question belongs to SO since it is maybe to broad, but I don't know where to ask it (I did not find a better stackexchange site).

## Context

I'm using [UiAutomator](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) to write some Ui test on android. I created some functions to simplify the write of the tests like the one in the doc

```
public void startMainActivityFromHomeScreen() {
    /*Start the app from the home screen*/
}
```

As a developper, this works fine. But non technical peoples (contracting owner) can't easily use this functions to write tests.

## Needs

I'm searching for a way for non technical users to write some scripts using the function I already defined. Here is a dummy example (both script format and actions)

```
Suite: Launch the app twice from the home screen

Case: Launch the app for the first time
  Do startMainActivityFromHomeScreen
  Expect ...

Case: Launch the app for the second time
  Do startMainActivityFromHomeScreen
  Expect ...
```

The important point here is to interact with java functions. I know other tools like [calabash](http://calaba.sh/) but it does not provide java interfaces.

## Current approach

Here is an idea (nothing implemented)

1. Put all the functions in a lib
2. Write a groovy dsl (because groovy interact well with java) which allows non technical users to easily write scripts
3. Create a java program which will evaluate the groovy script and generate the android code source associated (with the lib (from (1)) as a gradle dependency).
4. Run `gradle androidTestCompile`

Since the functions are in a lib, developers can easily include and use it into their projects. So the same lib can be used for all users.

I hate this idea since I have to generate code source from my code, but this is the only one I have.

## Questions

- Is this approach as horrible as I think it is ?
- Do you know another way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#java, it's a library that accomplishes pretty much exactly what you're looking for by letting you associate regex's with Java test methods.

Your Java code would look something like:

```
@When("^I open the app from the (main|home) screen$")
public void openApp(String launchScreen) { 
    ... 
}
```

And the testing file would look like:

```
Feature: Launching app

Scenario: Launching from first screen
    When I open the app from the main screen
    Then I see a blue icon...

Scenario: Launching from second screen
    When I open the app from the second screen
    Then I see a green icon...
```